# Spark Structured Streaming and Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, spark-structured-streaming

My goal is to write transformed data from a MongoDB collection into Neo4j using Spark Structured Streaming. According to the Neo4j docs, this should be possible with the "[Neo4j Connector for Apache Spark](https://neo4j.com/docs/spark/current/streaming/)" version 4.1.2.

Batch queries so far work fine. However, with the following example below, I run into an error message:

```
spark-shell --packages org.mongodb.spark:mongo-spark-connector:10.0.2,org.neo4j:neo4j-connector-apache-spark_2.12:4.1.2_for_spark_3
```

```
val dfTxn = spark.readStream.format("mongodb")
.option("spark.mongodb.connection.uri", "mongodb://<IP>:<PORT>")
.option("spark.mongodb.database", "test")
.option("spark.mongodb.collection", "txn")
.option("park.mongodb.read.readPreference.name","primaryPreferred")
.option("spark.mongodb.change.stream.publish.full.document.only", "true")
.option("forceDeleteTempCheckpointLocation", "true").load()
```

```
val query = dfPaymentTx.writeStream.format("org.neo4j.spark.DataSource")
.option("url", "bolt://<IP>:<PORT>")
.option("save.mode", "Append")
.option("checkpointLocation", "/tmp/checkpoint/myCheckPoint")
.option("labels", "Account")
.option("node.keys", "txn_snd").start()
```

This gives me the following error message:

```
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Data source org.neo4j.spark.DataSource does not support streamed writing
```

Although the Connector should officially support streaming starting with version 4.x. Does anybody have an idea what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Incase, if the connector doesnt support streaming writes, you can try something like below.

you can leverage `foreachBatch()` functionality from spark structured streaming and write the data into Neo4j in batch mode.

https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#using-foreach-and-foreachbatch

```
def process_entry(df, id):
    df.write.ToNeo4j(url=url, table="mytopic", mode="append", properties=props)
    
query = df.writeStream.foreachBatch(process_entry).start()
```

In the above code, you can have your Neo4j Writer logic and you can write the data into database using batch mode.